# Batch renaming files with sed. Invalid reference on `s` command RHS

Tags: bash, sed

Given the following input:

```
task-rest_acq-mb01_bold_magnitude01a.json
task-stroop_acq-mb01_bold_magnitude01a.json
task-rest_acq-mb01_bold_magnitude01.json
task-stroop_acq-mb01_bold_magnitude01.json
task-rest_acq-mb02_bold_magnitude02_e2.json
task-stroop_acq-mb02_bold_magnitude02_e2.json
task-rest_acq-mb03_bold_magnitude03_e3.json
task-stroop_acq-mb03_bold_magnitude03_e3.json
```

I want the following output:

```
task-rest_acq-mb01_bold_magnitude01a.json # no change. 
task-stroop_acq-mb01_bold_magnitude01a.json # no change
task-rest_acq-mbme01_bold_magnitude01.json # changed acq-mb to acq-mbme
task-stroop_acq-mbme01_bold_magnitude01.json # same as above
task-rest_acq-mbme02_bold_magnitude02.json # same and removed _e2
task-stroop_acq-mbme02_bold_magnitude02.json # same as above
task-rest_acq-mbme03_bold_magnitude03.json # same and removed _e3
task-stroop_acq-mbme03_bold_magnitude03.json # same as above
```

That is, I want to perform two changes:

1. remove name suffixes when they are present, e.g **"_e2"**, and
2. change the name *acq_mb* to *acq_mbme*, when the filename (without extension) doesn't end with a letter (in my example the letter a).

I've tried the following regex on [regex101](http://www.regex101.com), and it matches exactly what I want, and stores the information in capture groups so I can properly rename my files:

```
(acq-mb)(.*_bold_magnitude\d*)([\.|_]+e\d)*\.
```

Therefore I tried using the following script for batch renaming:

```
for i in *; do       ##        /1              /2                 /3
  mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed "s/(acq-mb)(.*_bold_magnitude\d*)([\.|_]+e\d)*\./acq_mbme\2/"`";
done
```

I only want to keep capture group 2, so I don't use the other capture groups on the substitution string.
The problem is that I get the following error when trying out my script:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 51: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's
>   RHS

I would like to understand why this is happening, and how I can fix it so that my solution works. (GNU sed 4.2.2)

Thank you for taking your time to help me.

**EDIT**

The final solution (credits to the accepted answer):

```
for i in *; do
mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed -r "s/(acq-mb)(.*_bold_magnitude[0-9]*)([\.|_]+e[0-9])*\./acq_mbme\2./"`";
done
```

Comment: You need either to escape your grouping parenthesis (`\(...\)`) or to use `sed`'s `-r` extended regex flag

Comment: You might also look into using the `rename` command instead of writing your own loop with sed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the sed command you're looking for:

```
sed -r 's/(acq-mb)(.*_bold_magnitude[0-9]*)([\.|_]+e[0-9])*\./acq_mbme\2./'
```

`-r` in order to use `()` instead of `\(\)`.

`sed` doesn't know `\d`, use `[0-9]` instead.

change `acq_mbme\2` `acq_mbme\2.` or else you get e.g. `...magnitude02json`